# Super Dev Mode doesn't detect changes after recompiling

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I set up new eclipse workspace and downloaded project from SVN. I launched Super Dev Mode (gwt-2.7.0, chrome browser) and when trying to recompile it says "skipped compile because no input files have changed". It works well in old workspace but it doesn't in new one. I used the same glassfish domain (I undeployed old application, restarted glassfish, used maven clean, maven install options on project in new workspace and deployed ear file to glassfish).

It works when it's started for the first time (changes which are not deployed to glassfish are visible after launching Super Dev Mode) but it doesn't see changes made after Super Dev Mode was launched. I guess that it has to be due to some kind of invalid path set somewhere but I was looking for something suspicious in \glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_name\eclipseApps* and \Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-lotofnumbers.tmp* locations and I didn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your classpath look like? Possibly reorder sources to the front of the classpath.